# SQL query to change all attributes of a product to "use default website"

Tags: sql, magento

we have a lot of products which have certain attributes changed in a store view not to use the default website settings. like this:

[image]

we now need a script to generally change all products to this setting:

[image]

important is, that this happens for all attributes, especially the pictures:

[image]

any help is very appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First backup. Then run this SQL:

```
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_datetime WHERE store_id > 0;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal WHERE store_id > 0;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_gallery WHERE store_id > 0;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_int WHERE store_id > 0;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value WHERE store_id > 0;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_text WHERE store_id > 0;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE store_id > 0;
```

After that, rebuild all product related indexes and then clear the block html cache.

Comment: Run this on a development version of your website first!

Comment: Wholeheartedly agree with @JoshPennington